# Como se faz para juntar dados de outra tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como se faz para juntar dados de outra tabela.

No banco a baixo tenho 3 tabelas:

```
dados:    id, nome, end, tel... etc.... 
cidades:  id, nome_cidade
status:   id, nome_status


$sql = "SELECT * FROM dados ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na consulta");
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

$nome = $linha["nome"];      //aqui gravo o Nome Fulano
$cidade = $linha["cidade"];  //aqui gravo o id da Cidade
$status = $linha["status"];  //aqui gravo o id do status

}
```

Então ele me retorna:

```
Nome: Paulo  na cidade: 1  e status: 2
Nome: Rafael na cidade: 1  e status: 2
```

Como fazer que me retorne assim.??

```
Nome: Paulo  Cidade: Rio de janeiro Status: Ativo
Nome: rafael Cidade: São Paulo Status: inativo
```

Comment: Poderia colocar a estrutura completa da tabela `dados`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa fazer um `JOIN` nas suas tabelas.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT d.nome, c.nome_cidade AS cidade, s.nome_status AS status FROM dados d
  JOIN cidades c ON d.cidade = c.id
  JOIN status s ON d.status = s.id
```

Vai retornar:

```
+--------+----------------+---------+
|  NOME  |     CIDADE     | STATUS  |
+--------+----------------+---------+
| Paulo  | Rio de Janeiro | Ativo   |
| Rafael | São Paulo      | Inativo |
+--------+----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 7):

Na sua tabela dados, você precisar ter os id de cidade e status. Com esses campos em comum faça um `JOIN`, se o nome dos campos forem iguais é necessário dar um alias para cada um ou apenas colocar o campo correto(descrição) no `FROM` list.

Sua consulta deve ficar assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.*, c.nome_cidade, s.nome_status FROM dados as d
        INNER JOIN cidades as c ON d.id_cidade = c.id
        INNER JOIN status as s ON d.id_status = s.id  ";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
   $nome = $linha["nome"];
   $cidade = $linha["nome_cidade"];
   $status = $linha["nome_status"];    
   echo "Nome: $nome  Cidade: $cidade Status: $status";  
}
```

Evite colocar mensagens de erros que não ajudam em nada, quando estiver testando deixe a mensagem de erro banco aparecer. Mude:

```
or die ("Erro na consulta");
```

Por:

```
or die (mysql_error());
```

Existem diferentes tipos de joins um para cada situação, veja essas diferenças nesas pergunta: [Qual é a diferença entre inner join e outer join?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Answer (score 2):

segue um exemplo de como deve fazer, sei que o certo é usar INNER JOIN:

```
$sql = "SELECT  c.nome, d.nome_cidade, c.nome_status FROM cidades c, dados d, inativo i WHERE d.cidade = c.id AND d.status = i.id ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro na consulta");
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

    $nome = $linha["nome"];      //aqui gravo o Nome Fulano
    $cidade = $linha["nome_cidade"];  //aqui gravo o id da Cidade
    $status = $linha["nome_status"];  //aqui gravo o id do status

    echo "Nome: $nome  Cidade: $cidade Status: $status";
}
```